# HOw would I convert this to work in a c program?

Tags: c, arrays, assembly

```
 byte bigHeart[] = {
  B01100110,
  B11111111,
  B11111111,
  B11111111,
  B01111110,
  B00111100,
  B00011000,
  B00000000};
```

I'm trying to use it to print to an led screen. COnverting from ino to c to convert to assembly. Cant's quite get it to where the compiler likes it for disassembly from c

Comment: What language is it? I don't mean the code..

Comment: going from .ino (arduino sketch, where this works) to a c file (where I can't get it to work) for disassembly to a .asm file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in C.  The binary constants are converted to hexadecimal:

```
unsigned char bigHeart[] = {
    0x66,
    0xFF,
    0xFF,
    0xFF,
    0x7E,
    0x3C,
    0x00
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not in standard C but it is a proposed C++14 standard if you could use C++.

gcc supports it - see here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Binary-constants.html

So in gcc you could do like this:

```
unsigned char bigHeart[] = {
  0B01100110,
  0B11111111,
  0B11111111,
  0B11111111,
  0B01111110,
  0B00111100,
  0B00011000,
  0B00000000};
```